Convert Intl select to Dart list
In my Flutter application I show a series of YouTube videos via the youtube_player_iframe plugin.
The videos vary depending on the language, so I placed the YouTube codes into the localization files, via intl plugin.
I would like to read the line from the .arb file and turn it into a list via regex, but I can't read it all as a string.
Can anyone help me or have a better idea on how to handle this situation?
This is the select on the .arb file:
"youtubeVideo": "{choice, select, 1{W6wIEp-M4tg} 2{bXOr0G7v-9Q} 3{zFWdTv6-7ws} 4{z8oSo6qTmqk} 5{_d29LTKgCEA} 6{PH8Mmxxhq_E} other{}}",
  "@youtubeVideo": {
    "placeholders": {
      "choice": {}
    }
  }

This is a trivial regex, to try to read the line of the .arb file:
RegExp exp = RegExp(r'^[\w\W]+$');
String str = AppLocalizations.of(context)!.youtubeVideo.toString();
RegExpMatch? match = exp.firstMatch(str);

And this is what I obtain in the str variable:
Closure: (String) => String from Function 'youtubeVideo':.

Thank you

what do you exactly want to extract from the .arb?

@Mr.Irrelevant I want to read the content of the youtubeVideo as a String, so in the variable str I want {choice, select, 1{W6wIEp-M4tg} 2{bXOr0G7v-9Q} 3{zFWdTv6-7ws} 4{z8oSo6qTmqk} 5{_d29LTKgCEA} 6{PH8Mmxxhq_E} other{}}.
But doing String str = AppLocalizations.of(context)!.youtubeVideo.toString();, I get Closure: (String) => String from Function 'youtubeVideo':.
